# Many home screen widgets DO handle touch events, how do they do it?

Tags: android, android-widget

You can take a look at different standard Android widgets: Email, Gmail, Messages, etc. They have "Add new" or "Reload" buttons which change their background color while you touch them. Do you have any idea how it can be implemented? Because based on what I have read, only click events can be detected by RemoteViews, not touch events.

Comment: [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)?

Comment: You are right, and for the TextViews ColorStateList can be used as well. Thanks for the hint!